# Python Requests gets a faster reponse when timeout is set

Tags: python, python-requests

I am trying to download data from the https://aqs.epa.gov/data/api/ using python and the requests library

An example url to get some data is https://aqs.epa.gov/data/api/monitors/byState?email=test@aqs.api&key=test&param=42401&bdate=20150501&edate=20150502&state=49

By changing the timeout parameter in `requests.get()`, I get the data faster, even though no error is raised (see the documentation [here](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/quickstart/#timeouts)). You can test this by using the code below. Change the `timeout=5` to any value. Not including it, or setting it to `None` is the same.

```py
import requests
import json
url = "https://aqs.epa.gov/data/api/monitors/byState?email=test@aqs.api&key=test&param=42401&bdate=20150501&edate=20150502&state=49"

response = requests.get(url = url,headers=header,timeout=5)

print(response.json())
```

I think this has something to do with the read timeout. The connection does not timeout, so there is no error. But the read timeout does get hit. I think the data server keeps the connection alive even after it gives a response. The requests library just keeps waiting for more data because it doesn't know that it is done.

How would I go about getting the data immediately when a response is gotten, instead of waiting until the timeout (be it mine or the servers)

Comment: You should get ride of the `headers=header` parameter, I made a mistake in the example.

Comment: also, I think it is the connection timeout. Timeouts can have a tuple argument. The first being the connection, and the second being the read timeout. The time it takes to get the data out is only effected by the first argument in the tuple